# Chrome extension issue for audio playing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add audio playing and set duration.
But Can't see the time, min and second control bar.
Can someone help with this?

```
$("#audio").on("canplaythrough", function(e){
    var seconds = e.currentTarget.duration;
    var duration = moment.duration(seconds, "seconds");
    
    var time = "";
    var hours = duration.hours();
    if (hours > 0) { time = hours + ":" ; }
    
    time = time + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();    
    
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just add the time value to any element.
for example

```
$("#id).text(time);
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sounds great!! 
You can just accept my answer as the answer to your question ;)

Comment: sure thing. will do